# How to instance doctrine entity manager in a symfony2 class

Tags: class, symfony, doctrine, instance, entitymanager

I am new with Symfony 2 and Doctrine.

I have created a new class on my symfony project, which is located in:

```
project_folder/src/Libraries/Validarcontenido/Validarcontenido.php
```

I need to get the Doctrine Entity Manager instance in this class.

I have reading docs about it, and everyone says that i must add the class into the **services.yml** file, but didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Libraries\Validarcontenido;

use AdminBundle\Entity\Aportes;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Validarcontenido
{
    private $request, $post, $em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $this->post = $this->request->request->all();

        // gets doctrine instance
        $this->em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    }

}
```

And the **services.yml**:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    validarcontenido.service:
        class: Libraries\Validarcontenido\Validarcontenido
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

But Symfony returns me this error message:

```
 Attempted to call an undefined method named "getContainer" of class "Libraries\Validarcontenido\Validarcontenido".
500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedMethodException
```

What i am doing wrong? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that when i create the service instance in the controller i used this:

```
$my_class = new My_class();
```

And now i know that i have to use this:

```
$my_class = $this->get('service_name');
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the constructor to set the entity manager:

```
class Validarcontenido
{
    private $request, $post, $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $this->post = $this->request->request->all();
        $this->em = $em;
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way you must not recreate a new instance of `Request` like that. Use the `request_stack` service instead: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: I totally agree, @KévinDunglas. With my response, I just pointed out how to solve the question he was asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your class as a service in the service.yml as you already did, only you were almost there.

You need to change your class as this:

```
<?php

namespace Libraries\Validarcontenido;

use AdminBundle\Entity\Aportes;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Validarcontenido
{
    private $request, $post, $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $this->post = $this->request->request->all();

    // gets doctrine instance
    $this->em = $em;
}

}
```

Heres a working example (that provides the container): https://codedump.io/share/tpxgpEMJnaiW